# How to create a sequence numerical column based on two columns in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence, numeric

My dataframe "fsp" as 1702551 obs and 3 variables. It look like this:

```
tibble [1,702,551 x 3] 
 $ date       : Date[1:1702551], format: "2011-04-12" "2011-04-12" "2011-04-12" ...
 $ wavelength : num [1:1702551] 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 ...
 $ ID         : chr [1:1702551] "c01" "c01" "c01" "c01" ...
```

Quick explanation of the data: Per each "date" and "ID" I had a spectral data (not shown) throughout the wavelength interval (350 to 2300nm).
I want to create a new column "target_ID" with a sequence of repeating numers that increases to the next consecutive number each time date or ID changes.
For example for the first ID, "c01" and date "2011-04-12" I will have a column with the number 1 from the wavelength 350 to 2300. The next ID will have the number 2 and so on (along the dataframe "date" changes as well)

Example of what I want to achieve (look "target_ID"):

```
|date      |wavelength|ID  |target_ID|
|:---------|:---------|:---|:--------|   
|2011-04-12|350       |c01 |1        |
|2011-04-12|351       |c01 |1        |
|2011-04-12|352       |c01 |1        |
|2011-04-12|353       |c01 |1        |
|...…………………|...……………….|....|...…………….|        
|2011-04-12|350       |c03 |2        |
|2011-04-12|351       |c03 |2        |
|...……………..|...……………….|....|...………………|
|2011-04-13|350       |c01 |3        |
|2011-04-13|351       |c01 |3       |
```

This is the code that I already tried but without success:

```
fsp<-fsp %>%
group_by(date, ID) %>%
mutate(target_ID, count=n())
```

Any help will be much appreciatted.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should include code for at least a subset of your dataframe. Something like the output of dput(fsp, 10).
It would also make it easier to help you if you state your desired output clearly, showing examples. As you wrote, I am not sure whether you just want to use a sequence of integers like 1:nrow(fsp) for this new column, or if you want 1:nrow() for each group of "ID".

Comment: Well, the output dput will be a bit messy since the data strucutre is the same 1950 per 1950 obs. What I want is a new column "target_ID" with a number sequence, 1:nrow() for each "ID" and "date". Since each ID and date have 1950 obs. I want the number "1" for the 1950 obs, the number 2 for the next 1950 obs. and o on. The "ID" and "date" have to be included in the code because sometimes I have the same "date" for diferent "IDs".

Comment: @PKumar thats gives me a number sequence throughout all data points. What I want is a sequence of numbers based on the date and ID. Command like "The first date and ID in the begining are 1, when date or ID change it gets number 2 and so on…"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for the `rleid` function from the **`data.table`** package:

```
# example data
xx <- rep(Sys.Date(), 5)
xx <- c(xx, xx + lubridate::days(1))
id <- rep(c(1:4), c(2,3,3,2))
dat <- data.frame(date = xx, id = id)

#          date id
# 1  2021-03-29  1
# 2  2021-03-29  1
# 3  2021-03-29  2
# 4  2021-03-29  2
# 5  2021-03-29  2
# 6  2021-03-30  3
# 7  2021-03-30  3
# 8  2021-03-30  3
# 9  2021-03-30  4
# 10 2021-03-30  4

library(data.table)
dat_dt <- as.data.table(dat)
dat_dt[,target_id := rleid(date, id)]

 #          date id target_id
 # 1: 2021-03-29  1         1
 # 2: 2021-03-29  1         1
 # 3: 2021-03-29  2         2
 # 4: 2021-03-29  2         2
 # 5: 2021-03-29  2         2
 # 6: 2021-03-30  3         3
 # 7: 2021-03-30  3         3
 # 8: 2021-03-30  3         3
 # 9: 2021-03-30  4         4
 #10: 2021-03-30  4         4
```

And here's how you could use `%>%` and `mutate` to solve it:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    mutate(target_id = data.table::rleid(date, id))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code works but with my data the target_id mantain the same number "1" along the data. Maybe the column format is issue to run the code properly... The id as to be numeric? In my dataframe the "date" is double and the "ID" are characters.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to reestart R and the code works perfectly. Thank you.